# How to refresh textBlock Text after updating its text?

Tags: c#, windows, textblock

[code snippet link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOGCE.jpg)I am developing windows 8 application in C#. I have 2 textBlocks in my GUI. 
I get text input from user and assign it to textBlock1 using `textBlock1.Text = user input;`.
After that I call a method that gets some data from API in JSON and part of data it populated in textBlock2 using `textBlock2.Text = "specific data";`
but text of both text blocks is changed at same time that I don't want. according to code sequence text of textBlock1 should be changed earlier as textblock2 text change happens after call to API that take about 10 sec. 
How can I first change text of textBlock1?
help me out as i'm new to windows development.

Comment: It will help, if you post a code snippet.

Comment: @SeanStayn stayn i have added code snippet have a look. hope it clears what i'm trying

Comment: Post the code of the 'populateResponses' method.

Answer (score 0):

In your method, you use

```
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(userInput).Result;
string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

If you call an Async method, you should use the await statement, if the code should wait for the method call, like this:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(userInput).ConfigureAwait(false);
string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

But for that, you must change your method to async:

```
private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

Perhaps, it solves your problem.

Offtopic: Because you are new, I recommend visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) page and read them, to understand Stack Overflow better.

Update:
I forgot ".ConfigureAwait(false)"

Answer (score 0):

The API call locks the UI. If you want to update textblock1 before textblock 2 you have to make the call on a different thread.
Something like this should work.

```
//make the method async.
private async void button_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

//...

//assuming userMessage is textblock2.
userMessage.Text = await MakeAPICallAsync();


//...

}

//where MakeAPICallAsync() is another function defined as
private async Task<string> MakeAPICallAsync()
{
//API call;
return result;
}
```